# Parameter of a controller method in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, locale

I am quite new in Spring MVC World and I a question for you.

I have created a new Spring MVC project by the STS template.

So now I have a minimal project that, once that is executed, show an Hello World message with the current date and time shown

This is the code of the only controller class of this project:

```
package org.gnagna.bla;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

/**
 * Handles requests for the application home page.
 */
@Controller
public class HomeController {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

/**
 * Simply selects the home view to render by returning its name.
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
    logger.info("Welcome home! The client locale is {}.", locale);

    Date date = new Date();
    DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.LONG, locale);

    String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);

    model.addAttribute("serverTime", formattedDate );

    return "home";
}

}
```

So there is only one method called called **home** that handled HTTP GET Call toward the "/" URL, ok this is clear for me.

The thing that this is not clead is about the input parameter of this method, as you can see this method receives two input parameter:

1) The model

2) A Locale object that contain some information about the user

But: who create this Locale object and when this is passed as input parameter in my controller?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: This has nothing to do with your problem, but java convention states that method names should be verbs http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A LocaleResolver is doing that.

One such resolver is eventually used by the [HandlerMethodInvokere](http://static.springsource.org/spring-framework/docs/3.2.0.M2/api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/support/HandlerMethodInvoker.html) to inspect the parameters of the @RequestMapping method that you are invoking (the "home" method in your case). When it comes across a Locale parameter it simply uses the locale resolver to fetch a Locale object to pass as argument there.

You can see more information about it here:
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch16s06.html

http://templth.wordpress.com/2010/07/21/configuring-locale-switching-with-spring-mvc-3/

http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-internationalization-example/

Comment: mmm...I have alredy read some tutorial about internazionalization of a Spring app...but in this case I have not LocalResolver declared in servlet-context.xml and web.xml files...why?

Comment: If you don't specify any locale resolver, Spring simply defaults to [AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/i18n/AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver.html). So you always have one locale resolver.

Comment: Ok, say me if I have understand well how it work
Spring give me a local resolver by default, this look inside the header of my HTTP Request and so know my "locality" that is storede in a Locale object that I can pass as input parameter for my controller method to be used inside it...

Is it right?

Thanks

Comment: Yep, that's it. The default looks into the "accept-language" HTTP request header to extract the locale.

Comment: but now my only doubt is: WHY can I pass thise Locale object to whatever my method of a controller? Maybe it is a stupid question...but I ahve this doubt...

Comment: There are a ton of parameter types that are supported by default (i.e. they have default resolvers), you can see a list of those here [RequestMapping](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html). Locale is just one of them. So basically you can use any of those on your controller methods.

Comment: uhhhh ok Thank you very mucht !!! This is exactly what I was asking for !!! you could not do better

Answer (score 1):

In your GET request you can send locale information to the server by using special paramerter of that request like, `?language=en`. But the question is how your servlet container knows that the `language` parameter is the parameter bearing your locale information. To let the Spring MVC container know about this special locale parameter, you need two add the special interceptor in your `targer-servlet.xml` like bellow:

```
    <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
    <property name="paramName" value="language" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping" >
    <property name="interceptors">
       <list>
        <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The thing is now, your servlet container knows the value of the locale parameter passed with your GET request. But still you need someone to  change the locale based on the selected language link and display the message from properties file accordingly. A special bean named `localeResolver` comes to the rescue to do the job, like bellow:

```
    <bean id="localeResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
</bean>
```

Now if you like to use the locale object in your GET request handler method, you write the method signature like `public String home(Locale locale, Model model)`(like, what you have done). Then your servlet container gets an extra job of putting that locale object as your method parameter before invoking it and you get it inside your method like magic!